# Which assumptions on $Ω\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ do we need in order to show density of $C_c^∞(Ω)$ in $(L^p(Ω),\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{L^p(Ω)})$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$, $u\in\mathcal L^1(\Omega)$ and $$u_\varepsilon(x):=\frac 1{\varepsilon^d}\int_\Omega\rho\left(\frac{x-y}\varepsilon\right)u(y)\;{\rm d}\lambda(y)\;\;\;\text{for }\varepsilon>0\text{ and }x\in\mathbb R^d$$ where $\rho\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ has support in the unit ball and $$\int\rho\;{\rm d}\lambda=1\;.$$

> We can show, that if $u\in\mathcal L^p(\Omega)$ for some $p\in[1,\infty)$, then $u_\varepsilon\in\mathcal L^p(\Omega)$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ and $$\left\|u_\varepsilon-u\right\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\stackrel{\varepsilon\to 0}\to 0\tag 1$$ (see *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order* by *Gilbarg* and *Trudinger*, *Lemma 7.2*).

If $\Omega$ is bounded, then $u_\varepsilon\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ and we can conclude that $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $(L^p(\Omega),\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{L^p(\Omega)})$.

However, I found many lecture notes (as well as questions here on the board) where they state, that this result is true for any (open) subset $\Omega$. So, which assumptions on $\Omega$ do we really need and where can I found a rigorous proof for the result in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true for any open $\Omega$: you have to replace $u$ by the function
$$ \tilde{u}(x) = \begin{cases} u(x) & x \in \Omega \\ 0 & \text{else}  \end{cases} $$
Then you get bounds on the $L^p(\Omega)$-norms from the $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$-norms, and exactly the same proof applies. See, for example, p.64ff. of Lieb and Loss, *Analysis*, and particularly sections 2.16 and 2.19.

Comment: I know that $(1)$ can be shown for arbitrary (not even open) $\Omega$, but $u_\varepsilon$ is not necessarily compactly supported, if $\Omega$ is not bounded. So, either the $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ isn't dense in $(L^p(\Omega),\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{L^p(\Omega)})$, unless $\Omega$ is bounded, or we need an other proof for it. I would be happy, if you could tell me what you think of this.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: First find $n$ with $\|u - u_n\|_p < \epsilon$, where $u_n(x) = u(x) \cdot 1_{|x| \leq n}$. Then approximate $u_n$ by convolution. This shows density.

Comment: An alternative proof is to use step functions, which are dense by the definition of integrability. Then approximate the step functions with bump functions.